# How can I delete email sent to myself in Sent folder without deleting it in Inbox

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, delete

I sent an email to myself to keep it under a label, but when I delete it in *Sent Mail*, it deletes the message in the Inbox as well.

How can I keep it in Inbox (or under a different label) and delete it in *Sent Mail*? (Note this is different from other threads about deleting it in Inbox and keeping it in *Sent Mail*.)

Answer (score 3):

Gmail treats it like a single entity (email) instead of a sent-received pair, so if you delete it either from inbox or from *Sent messages*, it will be removed from both places.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off conversation view does not correct this. If you send from your Gmail account or any alias on that Gmail account, to any email address that comes into the email box on the same Gmail account you composed and sent the email from, then it will be treated like one email and you will not be able to delete the sent email separately from the received email because they are actually the same email.

I was hoping to send myself little reminders that I can then search in Gmail and just have them go strait to an archive or label without cluttering the sent bucket. I am going to try sending to myself from a webform on my server, and if that works, I will then send reminders from there and probably create an API to do so. Handy to send myself a calendar, meeting, map, or anything I want easy access to without jumping between apps or rebuilding search, tag, filtering or other features that are in Gmail.

Answer (score -1):

You can turn off the "conversation" feature in Gmail.

Settings --> General

[image]

This will split all messages up like they are in Outlook and others. It is a global setting though and I'm not sure you want to do that. If this is the only problem you have had with the conversation feature it is much like using a sledge to kill an ant. I find it is easier to read, but you have to decide for yourself.